# Is there a vertical menu in vaadin?

Tags: vaadin

i often used rich-faces for makes a user interface, recently i passed at vaadin.
Now i'm looking for a vertical  menù in vaadin, is there this kind of compontent?

Rich-faces has the followed:

http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=panelMenu&skin=blueSky

Answer (score 1):

If you're using vaadin 6.2+, you can use this add-on :

https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/melodion

But I suppose you are using vaadin 7, so you could probably achieve the same result either by

- updating this add-on (should be easy)
- using the accordion component: https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/layout.accordion.html

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately vaadin provides only a menubar.

If you have experience in html and css, you can create your own vertical menu and then use vaadin CustomLayout to embed it in a panel.

For example you can try something like this.

You should create an html file:

```
<table width="100%" height="100%">
  <tr height="100%">
    <td>
      <table align="center">
        <tr>
          <td align="left">Menu 1</td>
          <td><div location="menu1"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">Menu2</td>
          <td><div location="menu2"></div></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then you should embed it in vaadin in this way:

```
// Have a Panel where to put the custom layout.
Panel panel = new Panel("Menu");
panel.setSizeUndefined();
main.addComponent(panel);

// Create custom layout from "yourfile.html" template.
CustomLayout custom = new CustomLayout("layoutname");

//the style name refers the one you should define in css
custom.addStyleName("customlayoutexample");

// Use it as the layout of the Panel.
panel.setContent(custom);

// Create a few components and bind them to the location tags
// in the custom layout.
TextField menu1 = new TextField();
custom.addComponent(menu1, "menu1");


TextField menu2 = new TextField();
custom.addComponent(menu2, "menu2");
```

Pay attention at binding location name with component name.

If you want to add some javascript to xml (for open/close menu elements) you should write it directly in tag attribute.